# Looking for an application to map business ecosystems

Tags: drawing, business-card

I'm looking for an application or sowftware to map business ecosystem.

A part of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_ecosystem) from Wikipedia :

> [Business ecosystem is] an economic community supported by a foundation of interacting organizations and individuals—the organisms of the business world. The economic community produces goods and services of value to customers, who are themselves members of the ecosystem. The member organisms also include suppliers, lead producers, competitors, and other stakeholders.

Here is a simple visual example of Apple's one :

[image]
(Image from: https://www.slideshare.net/janschmiedgen/business-ecosystem-design)

I'm looking for an application that :

- Helps **map** and schematize different entities (as described above( and links between them
- Can manage and store precise informations about them, like a private **business cards organizer** would do
- Allows to map with different **layers** (with option to make them appear / disappear)

I am not looking for :

- General schemas/drawing applications like Google Draw & My Map (on Drive), Microsoft Office, LucidCharts.
- A contact organizer app not allowing schemas

Comment: Did you ever find a good tool?

Comment: @PaulMauge No, unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulMauge , I just found something by chance and I remembered I had asked a question here a few years ago. You can read the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Draw.io](https://Draw.io).
You can import svg, export pdf or png. And its free

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please explain how this recommendation meets the question's requirements?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A way to think about this problem (and its solution) is to read about [Sociogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociogram).

> A sociogram is a graphic representation of social links that a person
> has. It is a graph drawing that plots the structure of interpersonal
> relations in a group situation.

Then, some software can help to create the ecosystem map mentioned in the question, but not with all the features asked.